# Error while using index method of Array class

Tags: arrays, swift

I have created a custom class `MyArray` for practice and learning. I have created a few methods inside that class and an internal array. I am facing an error while using the `index(of: )` method on the internal array defined inside the class. Code of my class is as below:

```
public class MyArray<Element> {
    private var factorialNumber: Double = 0
    private var arr: [Element] = []
    internal var instance: MyArray?

    private init() {}
    public func removeElement(_ item: Element) -> [Element] {
        var found = true
        while found {
            if arr.contains(item) { // ERROR: Missing argument label '"where:" in call
                let index = arr.index(of: item) // Error: cannot invoke index with an argument list of type (of: Element)
                arr.remove(at: index!)
            } else {
                found = false
            }
        }
        return arr
    }

    public func removeFirstOccurance(of value: Element) -> [Element] {
        let index : Int = arr.index(of: value)

        arr.remove(at: index!) // ERROR: Cannot force wrap value of non optional type Int
        return arr
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason of the errors is that `Element` does not conform to `Equatable`.

Comment: Hi Vadin, thanks for the reply. But I am not able to understand that the internal array "arr" confirms to Equatable protocol and it's method index(of: ) has the parameter of type "Element". I am just using the actual array within my custom class. Shouldn't it work in this case !!

Comment: In the API `index(of: item)` the type of *item* must conform to `Equatable`